# CALayer - Translating an image while keeping the mask static

Tags: ios, core-graphics, mask

I have a CALayer that contains an image and has a mask on top of it.

> CALayer *firstLayer = [CALayer layer];
>
> ```
> firstLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
> firstLayer.frame =  curveView.frame;
> firstLayer.position = CGPointMake(curveView.frame.origin.x + 100, curveView.frame.origin.y + 100);
> firstLayer.name = @"FirstLayer";
> [self.view.layer addSublayer:firstLayer];
>
> CALayer *firstImageLayer = [CALayer layer];
> firstImageLayer.frame = firstLayer.bounds;
> firstImageLayer.masksToBounds = NO;   
> firstImageLayer.name = @"FirstImageLayer";
> firstImageLayer.contents = (id)first.CGImage;
> [firstLayer addSublayer:firstImageLayer];
> ```
>
> firstImageLayer.mask = [cM setMaskOnLayer:firstImageLayer
>   :@"FirstColor" :&error];

I want to translate/pan/drag the image contained in the base layer, while keeping the mask fixed. (A bit like viewing the image from inside a fixed window)

```
  for (CALayer *subLayer in firstLayer.sublayers) {

    // p is the touch coordinate

/*First Thing I tried*/          
CAShapeLayer *mask = (CAShapeLayer *)subLayer.mask;
 mask.position = p;
/*Moves the mask, not the image*/


/*My second approach*/
     subLayer.frame = CGRectMake(subLayer.frame.origin.x + p.x, subLayer.frame.origin.y+p.y, subLayer.frame.size.width, subLayer.frame.size.height);
/*Moves the entire thing… image+mask - both*/


/*Final desperate approach*/
             for (CALayer *subLayer2 in subLayer.sublayers)
             {
                 sublayer2.position = p;
             }
/*Nothing happens*/
 }
```

Help me.

Comment: how to solved this issue  can you share some code pls help me

Answer (score 1):

Did you have try apply the inverse transform of ImageLayer to the MaskLayer ?

```
CALayer* imageLayer = ...;
 CALayer* maskLayer = ...;
 CGAffineTransform inverse = CGAffineTransformInvert(imageLayer.affineTransform);
 maskLayer.affineTransfrom = inverse; //assign everytime imageLayer move or change
```